# Initializing Mutable Arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, initialization

I am still new to Objective C and I was wondering if there were any differences between the following two sets of code, is there any specific reason for using a local variable first?

```
NSMutableArray *MoviesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.GlobalMoviesList = MoviesList;
```

OR

```
self.GlobalMoviesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I am trying to find out what the difference between the two methods is? Appreciate if you can point me to some articles or topics that discuss that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These declarations are equal. Just don't forget that if your GlobalMoviesList is retain property (or strong, if you use arc), you should release instance after setting, or set autoreleased object.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, so if I use the first method, I will need to release the variable MovieList if i choose GlobalMoviesList to be Strong.???

Comment: actually, I did not work with arc yet, but if I understand right, strong property is almost the same as retain property. So, if will retain your object after being set. and, as I've said before, you can just use autoreleased instance

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is almost no difference.

Sometimes, when you call some methods on the new array, having a local variable may improve readability.

Anyway, it's just a matter of tastes.